# Nest can't resolve dependencies of the RolesGuard. Please make sure that the argument Reflector at index [1] is available in the PhotoModule context

Tags: nestjs

When I use rolesGuard before any handler Reflector error coming up. Please support me to deal with this thing.

Here, i am using rolesGuard.

```
import {
Controller,
Post,
Body,
UseGuards,
} from '@nestjs/common';
import { PhotoService } from './photo.service';

import { CreatePhotoDto } from './dto/create-photo.dto';
import { Photo } from './models/photo.model';
import { ApiOperation, ApiTags } from '@nestjs/swagger';
import { PhotoLikeDto } from './dto/photo-like.dto';
import { Roles } from 'src/decorators/roles.decorator';
import { RolesGuard } from 'src/guards/roles.guards';

@ApiTags('Photos')
@Controller('photo')
export class PhotoController {
constructor(private readonly photoService: PhotoService) {}

@ApiOperation({ summary: 'create new photo' })
@Roles('ADMIN')
@UseGuards(RolesGuard)
@Post()
async create(@Body() createPhotoDto: CreatePhotoDto): Promise\<Photo\> {
return this.photoService.create(createPhotoDto);
}
}
```

Comment: Can you show your `RolesGuard`? And can you showthe output of `npx nest info`?

Comment: @JayMcDoniel here is info: 
[System Information]
OS Version     : Windows 10
NodeJS Version : v18.12.1
NPM Version    : 8.19.2 

[Nest CLI]
Nest CLI Version : 10.1.9

[Nest Platform Information]
platform-express version : 10.1.0
mapped-types version     : 2.0.2
schematics version       : 10.0.1
sequelize version        : 10.0.0
swagger version          : 7.1.2
testing version          : 10.1.0
common version           : 10.1.0
config version           : 3.0.0
core version             : 10.1.0
jwt version              : 10.1.0
cli version              : 10.1.9

Comment: Cna you change `@Nestjs/core` in the `role.guard.ts` to `@nestjs/core`? I don't believe that `@Nestjs/` is a valid package name

Comment: @JayMcDoniel
You right. I had manually called Reflector because my vscode didn't automatically call the packages. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `RolesGuard`, the `Reflector` import should be `import { Reflector } from '@nestjs/core';`